# Why WPF gui not showing on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

the problem appeared after updating to windows 10, gui not showing or showing partially
after resizing the window everything appears
on windows 7, windows 8 and windows 8.1 all okay
what could go wrong?

for better problem understanding 
[this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2frs39v37joox5/gui%20problem.avi?dl=0)

Comment: @MarmiK I don't think this has anything to do with browser.

Comment: @MarmiK None taken. :) Hmm.. I think WPF has been a part of .NET Framework since version `3.0`. And all subsequent framework versions (`3.5`, `4.0`, `4.5`, and the latest `4.6`) all include WPF, so I don't think it is deprecated yet. Also, from the video, it looks like a desktop application, so unless OP is embedding a WebBrowser control, it probably not related to IE. By the way, can you explain about the IE specific code in WPF? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Ignatius i make a simple desktop application, not page, and I don't use browser

Comment: @OlegPiranit Yes of course.. You can check the answer below. Let me know if it doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since WPF uses DirectX to render its UI, I suspect that the issue is probably caused by graphic driver in Windows 10. Can you try to update your graphic driver and see if the problem persist?

Perhaps you can also try to force the WPF window to redraw itself by hiding it and then showing it back. Something like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    Show();
}
```

Let me know if this does not solve the problem.

**Update:**

[Someone in SO also had a similar problem in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003868/blank-wpf-child-windows-on-windows-10-temporarily-solved), he solved the problem by handling the window's `ContentRendered` event. Perhaps you can try if his solution works for you.

Comment: no, this code not help, I'm also try change Width/Height in Window_Loaded, also not help. 
I think problem in driver, I instal new drivers from official site but still not working, then I test in notebook with another video adapter and then work fine, and when I delete video adapter on PC also work fine, but just I instal drivers then again not work
what can be with drivers? maybe I must wait for next driver version for Windows 10?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. The problem most probably related to graphic driver. I also found a very similar problem with Windows 10, you can check the link in the updated answer above. Perhaps you can try if his solution works for you as a temporary solution until a proper driver is released.

Comment: I just rollback my intel(R) graphics driver and it does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the WPF application does not appear in development mode (within Visual Studio), but if you open Visual Studio as an administrator, it works.